# How to rotate tensor image randomly

Tags: tensorflow, random, tensorflow2.0

I want to rotate my images in parallel, using 'map', in the preprocessing stage.

The problem is that every image is rotated for the same direction (after one random number generated). But I want that each image will have different degree of rotation.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import math
import random
def rotate_tensor(image, label):
    degree = random.random()*360
    image = tfa.image.rotate(image, degree * math.pi / 180, interpolation='BILINEAR')
    return image, label

rotated_test_set = rps_test_raw.map(rotate_tensor).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

I tried to change the seed every call for the function:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import math
import random
seed_num = 0
def rotate_tensor(image, label):
    seed_num += 1
    random.seed(seed_num)
    degree = random.random()*360
    image = tfa.image.rotate(image, degree * math.pi / 180, interpolation='BILINEAR')
    return image, label

rotated_test_set = rps_test_raw.map(rotate_tensor).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

But I get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'seed_num' referenced before assignment
```

I use tf2, but I don't think it matter much (beside the code to rotate the image).

---

Edit: I tried what @Mehraban suggested, but it seems that rotate_tensor function is being called only once:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import math
import random

num_seed = 1
def rotate_tensor(image, label):
    global num_seed
    num_seed += 1
    print(num_seed) #<---- print num_seed
    random.seed(num_seed)
    degree = random.random()*360
    image = tfa.image.rotate(image, degree * math.pi / 180, interpolation='BILINEAR')
    return image, label

rotated_test_set = rps_test_raw.map(rotate_tensor).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

But it only prints "2" once. So I think the rotate_tensor is being called once.

---

Edit 2 - This is the function that show the rotated images:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

for X_batch, y_batch in rotated_test_set.take(1):
    for index in range(9):
        plt.subplot(3, 3, index + 1)
        plt.imshow(X_batch[index])
        plt.title("Predict: {} | Actual: {}".format(class_names[y_test_proba_max_index[index]], class_names[y_batch[index]]))
        plt.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: add `global seed_num` at the top of `rotate_tensor`. This way your code won't raise errors.

Comment: @Mehraban I tried global seed_num, but it seems that rotate_tensor functions is being called only once. I will edit the question.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. How do you check if all the images has been rotated by same degree?

Comment: @Mehraban I will add the code on the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you generate random numbers. You rely on `random` module though you should be using `tf.random` when dealing with tensorflow.

Here is a demonstration of how things change when you get random numbers from tf:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random

def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield [1.]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (float))

def m1(d):
    return d*random.random()

def m2(d):
    return d*tf.random.normal([])

[d for d in ds.map(m2)]
[0.17368042,
 1.5629852,
 1.2372143,
 1.8170034,
 1.7040217,
 -0.16738933,
 -0.11567844,
 -0.17949782,
 -0.67811996,
 -0.5391556]

[d for d in ds.map(m1)]
[0.8369798,
 0.8369798,
 0.8369798,
 0.8369798,
 0.8369798,
 0.8369798,
 0.8369798,
 0.8369798,
 0.8369798,
 0.8369798]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! The problem was really that I needed to use "tf.random.normal([])" instead of "random.random()". (: